# Issues installing devtools in R

Tags: r, devtools

Trying to install devtools, but keep getting the error

`Error : object ‘glue_collapse’ is not exported by 'namespace:glue'
 ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘usethis’`

Below is the full error code:

```
> install.packages('devtools', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')
also installing the dependency ‘usethis’


  There are binary versions available but
  the source versions are later:
         binary source needs_compilation
usethis   1.4.0  1.5.0             FALSE
devtools 1.13.6  2.0.2             FALSE

installing the source packages ‘usethis’, ‘devtools’

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/usethis_1.5.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 393903 bytes (384 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 384 KB

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/devtools_2.0.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 388141 bytes (379 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 379 KB

Warning in strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :
  unknown timezone 'zone/tz/2018i.1.0/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles'
* installing *source* package ‘usethis’ ...
** package ‘usethis’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error : object ‘glue_collapse’ is not exported by 'namespace:glue'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘usethis’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/usethis’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘usethis’ had non-zero exit status
Warning in strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :
  unknown timezone 'zone/tz/2018i.1.0/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles'
ERROR: dependency ‘usethis’ is not available for package ‘devtools’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/devtools’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘devtools’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/6m/np7rbj6d6hv6xf8y_9x5pq000000gn/T/Rtmp8PDiFb/downloaded_packages’
```

I've installed `tidyverse` which has the `glue` package encompassed within it, but still getting issues with `glue_collapse`. Additionally, is it possible to turn off lazy loading to fix the 'usethis' dependency issue? Tried searching ways, but no successful methods.

Comment: Fixed! Turns out I needed to install the `glue` package separately, which then fixed the `usethis` issue.

Comment: You could convert your comment to an accepted answer and mark this question as answered. It worked for me as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding my original comment as an answer to mark this resolved. Turns out I needed to install the glue package separately, which then fixed the usethis issue.